# Configure tomcat 8 for proxy support for https

Tags: apache, tomcat, https, proxy

I have webapp deployed in Tomacat8 on Ubuntu 12.10 which I can access it @

`https://serverhostname:8443/myapp/`. I have configured it for https by editing conf/server.xml

as follows.

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           keystoreFile="/root/.keystore" keystorePass="xxxx" 
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

I want it to access it at `https://serverhostname` at port 80. How to do it for https.

**Changes done so far**

Installed apache2

Ran commands

```
a2enmod proxy 
a2enmod proxy_http
```

Added to /etc/init.d/apache2.conf the lines.

```
ProxyPass        /myapp https://serverhostname:8443/myapp
ProxyPassReverse /myapp https://serverhostname:8443/myapp
```

Restarted apache2.

Changed the connector in conf/server.xml to

```
 <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               keystoreFile="/root/.keystore" keystorePass="xxxx" 
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
                proxyName="https://serverhostname" proxyPort="80"/>
```

But when I access `https://serverhostname`, I get 'Web page is not available".

Answer (score 1):

Got it working now on Ubuntu 12.10

changes done

/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName hostname.domain
...
...
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key
SSLProxyEngine on
ProxyRequests off
<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /myapp https://hostname.domain:8443/myapp
ProxyPassReverse /mpapp https://hostname.domain:8443/myapp

Redirect permanent / https://hostname.domain:8443/myapp
...

</VirtualHost>
```

Changes done to always use https.

/etc/apache2/sites-available/default

```
<VirtualHost>
..
...
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R,L]

</VirtualHost>
```

Changes done to /tomcat/conf/server.xml

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
               keystoreFile="/root/.keystore" keystorePass="xxxx" 
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" 
                proxyName="https://hostname.domain" proxyPort="443"/>
```